# Linear search algorithm with generic methods

Tags: c#, icomparable, linear-search

I have a problem with code.
I receive ***an error CS0311:** The type 'object' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'GenericMethods.search(T[], T)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'object' to 'System.IComparable'.*

**Task:**
Create a console app and write a generic method, Search [ int Search( T [ ] dataArray, T searchKey) ]
that searches an array using **linear search algorithm.**

a) Method Search should compare the search key with each element in the array until the search key
is found or until the end of the array is reached.

b) If the search key is found, return/display its location in the array (i.e. its index value); otherwise
return -1.

c) You need to populate the array with random values. ( int values – between 10 and 49, double
values between 50 and 99, char values between a and z). The size of array as 10.

d) Test this method by passing two types of arrays to it. (an integer array and a string array) Display
the generated values so that the user knows what values he/she can search for.

[Hint: use (T: IComparable) in the where clause for method Search so that you can use method CompareTo() to
compare the search key to the elements in the array]

**My code:**

using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace LinearSearch
{
class GenericMethods
{

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        object[] dataArray = new object[10];
        Random random = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.Length; i++)
        {
            int randomType = random.Next(1, 3);


            if (randomType == 1)


            {

                char randomChar = (char)random.Next('a', 'z');
                dataArray[i] = randomChar;


            }

            else if (randomType == 2)
            {


                double randomDouble = random.Next(50, 99);
                dataArray[i] = (int)randomDouble;
            }

            else
            {


                int randomInt = random.Next(10, 49);

                dataArray[i] = randomInt;


            }

        }

        Console.WriteLine("Generated array is: ");
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", dataArray));
       
       

        Console.WriteLine("Please, enter number from 10 to 99 or char from A to Z");
        object  userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(userInput);
        Console.WriteLine($"Location of search value {userInput}: {search(dataArray, userInput)}");



    }//end Main method


    private static int search<T>(T[] dataArray, T searchKey) where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        // default to -1 so that we can determine the search is successful when it becomes a positive value
        int arrayPosition = -1;
        for (int x = 0; x < dataArray.Length; x++)
        {
            T arrayElement = dataArray[x];
            // Console.WriteLine($"CompareTo result: {searchValue.CompareTo(arrayElement)}");
            if (searchKey.CompareTo(arrayElement) == 0)
            {
                // value is found
                arrayPosition = x;
                break;
            }
        }
        return arrayPosition;
    } // end searchValue




}
}
```

Could you please help me to fix this problem? I am new in C#..

Answer (score 1):

Instead of declaring `dataArray` as an `object[]` declare it as an `IComparable[]`. You wrote the type constraint limiting your generic type `T` to `IComparable`. `object` does not implement `IComparable`, so it is not a valid type

Comment: I tried, but I have the same error.

Comment: You need different array variables so you can call `search<char>()` and pass a `char[]` or call `search<double>()` and pass a `double[]`.

Comment: "**d)**" even says, *"Test this method by passing two types of arrays to it."* You're passing one type of array (i.e. `object[]`) with one or the other type (`char` or `double`) of *elements* in it.

Answer (score 0):

Lucky me, I always write generic searches for my code. For other search methods with Generics in C#, you can find them [here](https://github.com/Stratis-Dermanoutsos/Algorithms-C-Sharp).

```
public static int LinearSearch<T>(T[] array, T item) // O(n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        /* array[i] == item */
        if (Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(array[i], item) == 0)
            return i;

    return -1; // Not found
}
```

You must import 'System.Collections.Generic' in your file.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

Answer (score -3):

I found solution

```
string[] resultArray = Array.ConvertAll(dataArray, x => x.ToString());
```

After that  code works

Comment: Except now you're not comparing numbers or characters. You're comparing strings containing digit characters. You're going to get docked points for that. You haven't learned what the lesson was intended to teach you.

Comment: More importantly, you're learning a bad habit called "string obsession", where you deal with everything as strings instead of their proper data types. This will hinder you in all aspects of programming.

Comment: Do you mean I should create 3 arrays? 1) for int 2) for double 3) for char and test each this array using this method?

Comment: Yes. Once you've determined, randomly, which data type you're going to use, the branch of code that handles it should declare the array of that type *and* do the call to `search()`. Don't try to do a single call outside of those execution branches.

Comment: Oh, I thought I should create ONE  array, which has different types  (int, double and char) and find ....I didn't understand the task...Ok, thank you for help!

Comment: Wait... "d)" says to test with *"an integer array and a string array"*... that CAN'T be right. The integer makes sense... that's one of the types you can randomly generate according to the task description. But strings? What strings?! Ask your professor for clarification.

Comment: strings means char from A to Z - alphabet

Comment: If that's what it meant, it should've said "chars", not strings. They're not the same thing and the difference is functionally significant. And why, if it meant chars, did it not also include the remaining type, double? Why implement something and not test it? There's something wrong with the assignment.

Comment: yes..I don't understand too why I should create an array with double, but I will not use it

Comment: I'll say it again: **Speak with the professor and get clarification.** Requirements are often wrong or unclear, and programmers regularly have to get clarification. If you don't, you're bound to write something that isn't what the business/customer wanted.

Comment: This is not optimal and won't work as intended for most types. You should use a Comparer class instead.